# Retreive data from MySQL TEXT type in the same format

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, openvpn

I have a script which save a text file into MySQL. Here is the structure of the table :

```
create table save( 
    id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    client_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    file_txt TEXT NOT NULL,
    primary key (id) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In the following script I can add data to the table thank to this script :

```
#!/bin/bash
DB_USER="root"
DB_PASSWD=""
DB_NAME="test_save"
TABLE="save"

if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    client="$1"
    file=`cat /path/to/the/file`
    mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD $DB_NAME << EOF
        INSERT INTO $TABLE (client_name, file_txt) VALUES ("$client", "$file");
EOF
else
    echo "Missing client name"
fi
```

Here is the original content of the `file` (it's a openVPN file) :

```
client
proto udp
remote IPADRESS PORT
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_3sO2TzCVUQf73j0R name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-GCM
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
setenv opt block-outside-dns
verb 0
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
SOME KEY
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
SOME KEY
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
SOME KEY
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
key-direction 1
<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
SOME KEY
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
```

So I successfully added the content of the file into the database thanks to the script.

---

When I try to retreive the data with an another script :

```
#!/bin/bash
DB_USER="root"
DB_PASSWD=""
DB_NAME="test_save"
TABLE="save"

if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    client="$1"
    content_file=$(echo "SELECT file_txt FROM $TABLE WHERE client_name='$client'" | mysql $DB_NAME -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASSWD)
    echo "$content_file" >> new_file

else
    echo "Missing client name"
fi
```

But when I open the `new_file`, I get the following :

```
ovpn
client\nproto udp\nremote IPADRESS PORT\ndev tun\nresolv-retry infinite\nnobind\npersist-key\npersist-tun\nremote-cert-tls server\nverify-x509-name server_3sO2TzCVUQf73j0R name\nauth SHA256\nauth-nocache\ncipher AES-128-GCM\ntls-client\ntls-version-min 1.2\ntls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256\nsetenv opt block-outside-dns \nverb 0\n<ca>\n-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nSOME KEY\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n</ca>\n<cert>\n-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nSOME KEY\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n</cert>\n<key>\n-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nSOME KEY\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n</key>\nkey-direction 1\n<tls-auth>\n#\n# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key\n#\n-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----\nSOME KEY\n-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----\n</tls-auth>
```

So I don't know how I can retreive it in the same format. Or maybe should I store the file in a BLOB type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "same format", do you mean that you want it NOT shown on 1 line?
if so you can try replacing :

```
echo "$content_file" >> new_file
```

with:

```
echo -e "$content_file" >> new_file
```

The -e option should properly translate '\n' to new lines

Comment: Can you add an explanation to you answer? That would help to learn the difference

Comment: I think it was quite clear. I suggested the OP to use -e option of echo if he doesn't want everything to be shown on 1 line

Comment: I've seen that you've added an option to the call. But SO answers should always contain an **explanation** for such additions, such that one can not only read the answer and know that there is some option `-e` which magically solves this problem, but that one can know what this option does and **why** it is helpful in this case